# How to filter oAttachment.DisplayName by file extension?

Tags: vba, outlook

In VBA of Outlook 2013, I save attachments from incoming emails.

I want to filter by file extension and only save, for example, .FOO files.

I thought this would be a matter of saving the filename to a string:

```vb
Dim nameString As String
nameString = oAttachment.DisplayName
```

but `nameString = oAttachment.DisplayName` throws an error:

> "**invalid qualifier**"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than the `DisplayName` look at the `FileName`.

The code I use looks similar to:

```
Sub Test_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

     'when a new item is added to our "watched folder" we can process it
    Dim olAtt As Attachment
    Dim i As Integer


    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim sExt As String

    If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        For i = 1 To Item.Attachments.Count
            Set olAtt = Item.Attachments(i)

            sExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(olAtt.FileName)

            If Left(sExt, 3) = "xls" Then

            ElseIf sExt = "CSV" Then

            End If

            olAtt.SaveAsFile FILE_PATH & FILE_NAME
            Item.UnRead = False
            DoEvents
        Next
    End If
    Set olAtt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you - .FileName seems to have worked nicely, im intrigued why .DisplayName wouldnt though..!

Comment: MS says of the `DisplayName`:  _Returns or sets a String representing the name, which does not need to be the actual file name, displayed below the icon representing the embedded attachment._  So may not be the actual file name, while with `FileName` they say: _Returns a String representing the file name of the attachment._